# How to display database value with ñ

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

I tried many type of solution like:

-`htmlentities` -> When using this, all words have ñ will not display

-`htmlspecialchars` -> all words have ñ will be "?"

-`utf8_encode` ->all words have ñ will be "?"

-`html_entity_decode(htmlentities($test));` ->When using this, all words have ñ will not display

my code what just a simple select, this is my code:

```
if (isset($_GET['cityname1'])) 
{

$cityname = strval($_GET['cityname1']);
$cname = mysql_query("SELECT cityname FROM city WHERE provinceid = '$cityname' ORDER BY cityname ASC");

echo "<option value='0'>Select Territory</option>";

  while($provincerow = mysql_fetch_array($cname))
  {
  $pname = htmlentities($provincerow['cityname']);
  echo "<option value='{$pname}'>{pname}</option>";
  }
}
else
{
echo "Please Contact the technical team";
}
```

Comment: Sanitising is normally for inserting data, not selecting and presenting it - just use `$provincerow['cityname']`

Comment: sir i try echo $provincerow['cityname'], but the result is "Las pi?as"... the ñ just convert to ?(question mark) with black background

Comment: You will probably need to change the encoding on your database then

Comment: in that code all the word with ñ are not display, it was just simple select ?..... just displaying the output in dropdown box.. :(

Comment: can somebody try... you just have a value or words with ñ stored in database, then fetch all the value and display it in dropdown :( thanks for the help in advance and sorry for my newbie question

Comment: Make sure the charset in everywhere (browser, html, database, connection, etc.) are the same.

Comment: i set also the latin_swedish_ci to utf8_swedish_ci... is this ok? because some forum say they solve their problem.. but in my problem it was just null value using htmlentities, Las Pi?as value using utf8_decode, Las Pi�as value  using html_entity_decode, null value using htmlspecialchars

Comment: Thanks the help of other. I just solve my problem by adding to my sql mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8'", $db)... thanks all of you sir

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` interface, it is going away soon.  Switch to `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: Do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...;`  If you don't see `C3B1` for the hex for `ñ`, then you have problems in the `INSERT` side.

Comment: The black diamond (�) is the browser's way of saying wtf.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, you have stumbled into the wondrous world of character encodings in browsers, PHP and MySQL.

Handling these characters is not something trivial since it is dependent on a number of factors. Normally speaking communication between PHP and MySQL is not in UTF-8 meaning that special characters (like ñ) get jumbled. So [setting the connection](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) to UTF-8 is a good start. Furthermore, it can be the case that PHP is not operating in a UTF-8 compliant manner, which can be checked (and set) using the function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

When this settings have been set correctely, you should be able to use the html_entities function to properly replace the character to the HTML character encoding (ñ).

The main problem with communcation between different services (like PHP and MySQL) is that when they are not using the same character encoding, characters (which are basically numbers) will be jumbled. Since both MySQL and PHP would be using different numbers for a certain character. For non special characters (like the non-accented alphabet) this works out, since these are extremely standardised, yet for more odd characters there still is some struggle as you have experienced.

Note that this answer assumes a basic setup, if I have made an unjustified assumption, please provide feedback, then I can help you further.

Comment: sir thank you for your concern. :) i just solve my problem :) just adding


 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db); 
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET 'utf8'", $db

in my mysql connection :)

http://community.sitepoint.com/t/php-mysql-and-latin-characters-aeiou-and-n-problem/3684/7